# Can I create multiple secondary indexes on a same table in RethinkDB and use them on different queries?

Tags: indexing, rethinkdb, database, nosql

I'm confused by the rethinkdb docs.

I have a table which will contain potentially millions of entries. 
Here is how all my queries look like (pseudocode):

```
- all where column1 == ''
      - filter where column2 == '' AND column3 == '' orderBy dateColumn7.field1

- all where column1 == ''
      - filter where column2 == '' AND column4 == '' orderBy dateColumn7.field2

- all where column1 == ''
      - filter where column5 == '' AND column6 == '' orderBy dateColumn7.field3
```

So my queries are all searching by column1, and then they have some specific filters, depending which query I call, and an orderBy, skip and limit for paging, etc.

Problem: I read in rethinkdb docs that .filter() does not work with secondary indexes, plus orderBy is limited to 100k entries, so now I must give up using .filter(), and do all my queries with getAll.

Question: Should I now create an index for each query, is that the recommended practice? E.g.:

```
indexCreate('ixQuery1', [column1, column2, column3, dateColumn7(field1)]
indexCreate('ixQuery2', [column1, column2, column4, dateColumn7(field2)]
indexCreate('ixQuery3', [column1, column5, column6, dateColumn7(field3)]
```

...and use each of them with the respective queries? Is that the best practice, if I want to do searches for big tables?
Or can I somehow keep using filter and orderBy() and STILL not lose records when I expect that my query searches all of them?

Let me know if my question is unclear.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in that case you will need a separate index for each one.